# Access object created in one class into another

Tags: java, class, object

I have a primary class as below:

```
public class classB{

  public classC getObject(String getstring){
     return new classC(getstring);
    }
}
```

The `classC` has a contructor:

```
public class classC{

 String string;

 public classC(String s){
  this.string = s;
 }

 public methodC(int i){
   <using the `string` variable here>
 }
}
```

Now I've a `classA` which will be using the object created in `classB`(which is of course, an instance of `classC`).

```
public classA{
  int a = 0.5;

  <Get the object that was created in classB>.methodC(a);

}
```

This is needed as a variable is created on some actions from the user and stored in `classB` and this would be further used in `classC`'s methods. Creating a new object will render my variable in `classB` set to null which isn't intended.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: need more info... preferably your complete code..

Comment: Question not understandable ... What is the real question ?

Comment: Based on classes above     public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        ClassC classC = classB.getObject("deneme");
        classC.methodC(1); } just workes fine. What are u excatly asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the `Brand` is a lightweight objects and `Run` is heavyweight then creating a field with the container for the lightweight objects and hiding it is a good idea.

But the `Brand` needs access the container it belongs to it could be done with the mapping but we are simply inject the `Run` to the `Brand` so it's better implement the `Runable` or annotate it with JSR330. And accessing the container through the `Run` in the normal way.

```
class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Run r = new Run();
  }
}

class Run {
  private Container con1 = new Container();

  public Run() {
    Brand cola = new Brand("Coca Cola");
    Brand pepsi = new Brand("Pepsi");

    // Creates the container object "con1" and adds brands to container.
    add(cola);
    add(pepsi);
  }
  public void add(Brand b){
    con1.addToList(b);
    b.setRun(this);
  }

  public Container getContainer() {
    return con1;
  }
}

class Brand {
  // In this class I have a method which needs to accsess the con1 object
// containing all the brands and I need to access the method
  private String name;
  private Run run;

  public Brand(String name){
    this.name = name;

  }
  public void brandMethod() {
    if(getRun().getContainer().methodExample()) {        // Error here. Can't find "con1".**
      System.out.println("Method example returned true.");
    }
  }


  public Run getRun() {
    return run;
  }

  public void setRun(Run run) {
    this.run = run;
  }
}

class Container {
  // This class is a container-list containing all brands brands
  private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

  public boolean methodExample(){
    return false;
  }

  public void addToList(Object o) {
    list.add(o);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the object created in classB a static field should do the job

```
public class classB {

  public static objectCReference;

  public classC getObject(String getstring){
     objectCReference =  new classC(getstring);
     return objectCReference;
  }
}
```

Then you can access the reference in A

```
public classA {
  int a = 0.5;

  if (classB.objectCReference != null) { // Make sure to null check 
    classB.objectCReference.methodC(a); 
  }

}
```

Also please follow the language conventions and start your class names with capital letters.