# Java: Access object created in class A from within class B

Tags: java, object, reference

I'm struggeling with accessing an object and it's methods from another class.
I've written some code to illustrate my problem

NOTE: the following code is not compile- or runable, just to explain my issue.

```
class MainClass {
    public static void(String[] args) {
        Run r = new Run();
    }
}

class Run {

    Run() {
        Brand cola = new Brand("Coca Cola");
        Brand pepsi = new Brand("Pepsi");

        // Creates the container object "con1" and adds brands to container.
        Container con1 = new Container();
        con1.addToList(cola);
        con1.addToList(pepsi);
    }

}

class Brand {
// In this class I have a method which needs to accsess the con1 object
 containing all the brands and I need to access the method

    public void brandMethod() {
        if(con1.methodExample) {        **// Error here. Can't find "con1".**
            System.out.println("Method example returned true.");
        }
    }

}

class Container {
    // This class is a container-list containing all brands brands

    public boolean methodExample(){
    }
}
```

I am struggling to access the "con1" object from within the Brand class.
How can I get access to "con1"?

Comment: I googled your exact question title and found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570393/access-object-created-in-one-class-into-another You are expected to do at least this much research before posting to SO.

Comment: the problem is not how to access the object but how to access it right?

Comment: See also [Access object created in one class into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570393/access-object-created-in-one-class-into-another/14885596#14885596)

Answer (score 1):

I would call `Brand` with the collection e.g.

```
brand.addTo(collection);
```

e.g.

```
public class Brand {
   private Container container;
   public void addTo(Container c) {
      c.addToList(this);
      container = c;
   }
}
```

The brand can then add itself, and hold a reference to the collection. It does mean that the brand has a reference to a single collection, and I'm not sure that's really what you want.

A slightly better solution is to provide the container upon construction of the `Brand`, and the `Brand` then adds itself once only to the collection, and has a reference to the collection from the outset.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is a good idea. Creating a new Brand and send the collection with it from the Run class. And then call the brand with its collection. Though I don't know how i should write this. Can you help?

Comment: See above for additional advice

Answer (score 0):

You must use a reference to the a `Container` object, and initialize it. Before the error line:

```
    Container con1 = new Container();  <-- the inicialization by creating a new object.

               ^
               |
               |
       the reference/variable
```

UPDATE TO ANSWER COMMENT:
You will have to pass the instance; most usually as a parameter to the method. I fear that you have studied the Java basics too little, the question has so many things wrong.

Search the following concepts :

- variables and its scopes.
- local variable vs instance variable vs static variable.
- method parameters.

Comment: But by adding Container con1 = new Container(), I am loosing the data stored in the original con1 container. I need to access the con1 WITH the stored brands.